# Every nonzero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be scaled to be arbitrarily close to $\mathbb{Z}^n-\{0\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, integer-lattices

> **Problem.** Show that for all nonzero $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $r>0$ such that $\operatorname{dist}(rv,\mathbb{Z}^n-
> \{0\})<\epsilon.$

In other words, we must show that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $w\in\mathbb{Z}^n-\{0\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $|v-w|<\epsilon$.

> **Bonus question.** Can we take $w$ to be arbitrarily large?

**Attempts.** The case $n=1$ is trivial: we can take $r=1/v$ so that $rv=1$. But that approach obviously doesn't generalize to $n>1$. Any idea?

More generally, if $v$ is rational, say $v_i=a_i/b_i$, then we can take $r=b_1\cdots b_n$ so that $rv\in\mathbb{Z}^n-\{0\}$.

Comment: See the "Simultaneous Version" section of [Dirichlet's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem).

Comment: to expand very slightly on Cave's comment: the answers are yes and yes. with the notation of wikipedia's article, take $w=(p_i)_i$ and then you have $\|w-v\| \leq 1/N^d$ which goes to zero as $N \to \infty$.

Answer (score -2):

What you refer to as the 'dist()' function is more commonly referred to as the *vector norm*, a function which takes a vector and produces the 'length' of a vector.  When you scale a vector by a constant, the norm of the vector scales by that constant (at least for the usual norm in this case).  It follows that the argument given for n=1 can be used nearly verbatim, all you need to do is translate from scaling the vector to scaling the norm.

Comment: No, that's not what the distant function is.

Comment: It is defined for any $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ by $$\mathrm{dist}(v,A)=\inf\{|v-a|:a\in A\},$$ where $|\cdot|$ is the vector norm you are referring.

Comment: @PMar : Are you the same user as the following other PMar: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/349761/pmar, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/347147/pmar, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/325605/pmar, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/344183, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/357091, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/358074, https://math.stackexchange.com/users/369583/pmar. If this is the case, could you please [merge](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts?

Comment: Regardless of being correct or not, this is more suitable for a comment rather than for an answer.